# Ctypes: DataTypes from C-definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, python-cffi, llvmlite

I have the address of a function and also its "c-like" representation (from [llvmlite](http://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binding/examples.html), but this is not that important).

For a function, which adds up two double values and returns them the code would look like this: `cfunc = CFUNCTYPE(c_double, c_double, c_double)(func_ptr)`

That would work quite well, however my function's argument can vary in type and number. In python, this is solvable with some `for arg in args` generator.

However i have no tool (or at least i found none) how to "convert" or parse my types to the ones of ctype.

The arguments are [llvmlite-Type](http://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ir/types.html) objects, so i have a c-like type representation availible.

---

My approach would be to create a dict, which can map llvmlite-Type objects, or the c-representation to the Type objects of ctypes. A little parser could help too.

Doesn't ctype provide something like this already? A magic function: 
`ctypes.magic("double") == ctypes.c_double`

I am not bound to ctypes. I know CFFI exists, however i have 0 experience with it and as far as i look in the docs, i couldn't find even the basic solution for a single function address.

I am aware that my use case is rather rare, since both of those libraries are more concerned about libraries and not particular function's address.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i am just using a dict with all the possibilities. Since i will probably be only bound to llvmlite there are not that many options.
`{str(ir.DoubleType()): ct.c_double, ....}`